# How to hide the default iOS volume display and use a custom UI element for display

Tags: ios, swift

iOS use a (stupid) volume display that overlays most of the screen. If a user is watching a video at the time, the volume display gets in the way and usually forces the user to pause the video and rewind it a couple of seconds.

I would like to know how to hide the default volume UI display, and show my own design instead.

This has been proved possible from Snapchat's update almost 12 months ago. They display their own volume bar at the very top of the screen that overlays the status bar instead, which in my opinion is a fantastic UI approach.

Snapchat's volume UI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTjzmyjxXqw

I have done some research online and was unable to find anything of use.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193626/cleanest-way-of-capturing-volume-up-down-button-press-on-ios-8