# How to detect volume button press on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, volume

I searched the solution for hours and it seems that `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` should work. But after I finished the code I didn't see any callback when pressing the volume button. Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
NSLog(@"init finished");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

float volume =
[[[notification userInfo]
  objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
 floatValue];

NSLog(@"current volume = %f", volume);

}
```

Comment: have u try with "AVAudioSession"

Comment: try with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36081853/3789527

Comment: Also I have tried to put code in Appdelegate but it still didn't work.

Comment: I tried [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil] but still failed.

Comment: @Signo The solution works fine. However, it detected  volume change but not key press event.