# How to catch ios device button press in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to catch sound volume button press inside my react-native application. Couldn't find anything in docs.

Comment: You may have to write a wrapper. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/36081853/3574819

Comment: @Victor L. how did you solve this ?

Comment: @David, it was long ago, I've got no code left, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a native module as per FuzzyTree's comment however if you want something that's ready out of the box you could use https://github.com/IFours/react-native-volume-slider and make it hidden. The onValueChange callback is called upon the iOS device volume controls being changed.

Another idea could be to look into the aforementioned module and just take out what you need to form a new module and publish it for the benefit of everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-native-system-setting` package with `addVolumeListener` listener. Something like this

`componentDidMount() {
    // listen the volume changing
    this.volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener(data => {
      // your action here
    });
}`