# Get notification on volume button press event in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i press volume button three times its need to show notification. i want to integrate this feature in my app.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need alarm/local notification ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam  i want to send message to specific number on volume button press

Comment: may be this link will help you out to know about volume event :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193626/cleanest-way-of-capturing-volume-up-down-button-press-on-ios-8

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons

Answer (score 1):

First, you initialise the AVAudioSession and add a listener by:

```
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
[audioSession addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"
                      options:0
                      context:nil];
```

Then you store the current system volume by:

```
float currentVolume = [audioSession outputVolume];
```

Then observe the volume change notification:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"outputVolume"]) {
        float newVolume = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
    }
}
```

You compare the newVolume and the currentVolume to determine the expected outcome.