# Volume Control With UISlider Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uislider

I'm creating a music app and I'm using an `UISlider` for the music volume control. the problem is when I press the volume button on the iPhone / iPad `UISlider` does not change or move. I've been looking for where to get no referrals.

This is the code I use:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.slider.setValue(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume, animated: true)
        }
}

@IBAction func volumeControlSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        slider = (MPVolumeView().subviews.filter { NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider" }.first as! UISlider)
        slider.setValue(sender.value, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: Don't use a `UISlider`, use an `MPVolumeView`. You can turn off the icon used to change the output device.

Comment: [Stack overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193626/cleanest-way-of-capturing-volume-up-down-button-press-on-ios-8) Please refer this link.

Comment: I've used MPVolumeView but it still does not change if pressed volume up / down button

Comment: func setupVolumeSlider() {
        volumeParentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: volumeParentView.bounds)
        for view in volumeView.subviews {
            let uiview: UIView = view as UIView
            if (uiview.description as NSString).range(of: "MPVolumeSlider").location != NSNotFound {
                mpSlider = (uiview as! UISlider)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func volumeChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        mpSlider.value = sender.value
    }

Comment: In that code you are not adding the `MPVolumeView` you create to the view hierarchy, so it is not going to be on the screen.

Comment: Forgive me. I do not understand what you mean ... can give a simple code example