# iOS Volume programming on swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm trying to repurpose the volume button on my app to go from email bar to password bar by clicking on the volume button. is that possible?

Comment: There are some ways of doing this but Apple would not approve an app that does this with very few exceptions, like camera apps. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28193626/730701)

Comment: thank you very much Adam. I'm only trying to use the app between my coworkers and I. My idea is to to go from email bar to password bar by clicking on the volume button. is that something I can do?

Comment: See the link from my previous comment